# Ошибка с заменой букв на странице

Tags: javascript, html

У меня такой код:

```js
var transformConfig = {
  latin: [
  ['А', 'A'],
  ['а', 'a'],
  ['Ә', 'Á'],
  ['ә', 'á'],
  ['Б', 'B'],
  ['б', 'b'],
  ['В', 'V'],
  ['в', 'v'],
  ['Г', 'G'],
  ['г', 'g'],
  ['Ғ', 'Ǵ'],
  ['ғ', 'ǵ'],
  ['Д', 'D'],
  ['д', 'd'],
  ['Е', 'E'],
  ['е', 'e'],
  ['Ж', 'J'],
  ['ж', 'j'],
  ['З', 'Z'],
  ['з', 'z'],
  ['И', 'I'],
  ['и', 'ı'],
  ['Й', 'I'],
  ['й', 'ı'],
  ['К', 'K'],
  ['к', 'k'],
  ['Қ', 'Q'],
  ['қ', 'q'],
  ['Л', 'L'],
  ['л', 'l'],
  ['М', 'M'],
  ['м', 'm'],
  ['Н', 'N'],
  ['н', 'n'],
  ['Ң', 'Ń'],
  ['ң', 'ń'],
  ['О', 'O'],
  ['о', 'o'],
  ['Ө', 'Ó'],
  ['ө', 'ó'],
  ['П', 'P'],
  ['п', 'p'],
  ['Р', 'R'],
  ['р', 'r'],
  ['С', 'S'],
  ['с', 's'],
  ['Т', 'T'],
  ['т', 't'],
  ['У', 'Ý'],
  ['у', 'ý'],
  ['Ұ', 'U'],
  ['ұ', 'u'],
  ['Ү', 'Ú'],
  ['ү', 'ú'],
  ['Ф', 'F'],
  ['ф', 'f'],
  ['Х', 'H'],
  ['х', 'h'],
  ['Һ', 'Һ'],
  ['һ', 'h'],
  ['Ц', 'Ts'],
  ['ц', 'ts'],
  ['Ч', 'Ch'],
  ['ч', 'ch'],
  ['Ш', 'Sh'],
  ['ш', 'sh'],
  ['Ы', 'Y'],
  ['ы', 'y'],
  ['І', 'I'],
  ['і', 'i'],
  ['Э', 'E'],
  ['э', 'e'],
  ['Ю', 'Iý'],
  ['ю', 'iý'],
  ['Я', 'Ia'],
  ['я', 'ia'],
  ['Щ', ''],
  ['Ь', ''],
  ['Ъ', ''],
  ['щ', ''],
  ['ь', ''],
  ['ъ', ''],
  ['ё', ''],
  ['Ё', ''],
  ],
  cyrillic: [
  ['А', 'A'],
  ['а', 'a'],
  ['Á', 'Ә'],
  ['á', 'ә'],
  ['B', 'Б'],
  ['b', 'б'],
  ['V', 'В'],
  ['v', 'в'],
  ['G', 'Г'],
  ['g', 'г'],
  ['Ǵ', 'Ғ'],
  ['ǵ', 'ғ'],
  ['D', 'Д'],
  ['d', 'д'],
  ['Е', 'E'],
  ['е', 'e'],
  ['J', 'Ж'],
  ['j', 'ж'],
  ['Z', 'З'],
  ['z', 'з'],
  ['I', 'И'],
  ['ı', 'и'],
  ['I', 'Й'],
  ['ı', 'й'],
  ['К', 'K'],
  ['k', 'к'],
  ['Q', 'Қ'],
  ['q', 'қ'],
  ['L', 'Л'],
  ['l', 'л'],
  ['М', 'M'],
  ['m', 'м'],
  ['N', 'Н'],
  ['n', 'н'],
  ['Ń', 'Ң'],
  ['ń', 'ң'],
  ['О', 'O'],
  ['о', 'o'],
  ['Ó', 'Ө'],
  ['ó', 'ө'],
  ['P', 'П'],
  ['p', 'п'],
  ['R', 'Р'],
  ['r', 'р'],
  ['S', 'С'],
  ['s', 'с'],
  ['Т', 'T'],
  ['t', 'т'],
  ['Ý', 'У'],
  ['ý', 'у'],
  ['U', 'Ұ'],
  ['u', 'ұ'],
  ['Ú', 'Ү'],
  ['ú', 'ү'],
  ['F', 'Ф'],
  ['f', 'ф'],
  ['H', 'Х'],
  ['h', 'х'],
  ['Һ', 'Һ'],
  ['h', 'һ'],
  ['Ts', 'Ц'],
  ['ts', 'ц'],
  ['Ch', 'Ч'],
  ['ch', 'ч'],
  ['Sh', 'Ш'],
  ['sh', 'ш'],
  ['Y', 'Ы'],
  ['y', 'ы'],
  ['І', 'I'],
  ['і', 'i'],
  ['E', 'Е'],
  ['e', 'е'],
  ['Iý', 'Ю'],
  ['iý', 'ю'],
  ['Ia', 'Я'],
  ['ia', 'я'],
  ['Э', ''],
  ['э', ''],
  ]
};

function transform(type) {
  // выполняем дальше если есть такое свойство
  if (typeof transformConfig[type] !== 'undefined') {
    // находим все элементы на странице
    var collection = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
    // перебираем все элементы на странице
    for (var idx = 0; idx < collection.length; idx++) {
      element = collection[idx];
      // если у элемента есть свойство innerHTML, идем дальше
      if (typeof element.innerHTML !== 'undefined') {
        transformConfig[type].forEach(function(chars) {

          var pattern = new RegExp(
            chars[0],
            'g'
          );
          // изменяем innerHTML
          element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(
            pattern,
            chars[1]
          )
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.hidden-menu {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  list-style:none;
  padding-top: 20vh;
  padding-left: 0vh;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #B0E0E6;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
  transition: left .2s;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker {
  display: none;
}

.btn-menu {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #7B68EE;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: left .23s;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.btn-menu span {
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  transition: all .1s linear .23s;
  position: relative;
}
.btn-menu span.first {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu {
  left: 160px;
}
.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .hidden-menu {
  left: 0;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.first {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 10px;
}
.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.second {
  opacity: 0;
}
.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.third {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>test</title>

</head>
<body class="wrapper-seven-eight">
 <div id="particles-js"></div>

 <h1 class="wrapper-logo">test</h1>
 <button onclick="transform('latin')" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px">Латинский</button>
 <button onclick="transform('cyrillic')" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 400px">Кириллица</button>
 <h2 class="wrapper-welcome">test</h2>

 <!--Боковое меню-->
 <input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker">
 <label class="btn-menu" for="hmt">
  <span class="first"></span>
  <span class="second"></span>
    <span class="third"></span>
 </label>
 <ul class="hidden-menu">
    <Br><Br><li><a href="#">test</a></li><Br><Br>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li><Br><Br>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>  
 </ul> 

 <!--Скрипты-->
 <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Когда я пеняю данные 3 буквы, то заменяется нормально, но когда и заменяю весь алфавит, то у меня появляется код страницы HTML: class, span, &lt, &gt и др., всё это появляется! Можете подсказать, что мне делать чтобы это исправить?

Comment: добавь пример воспроизводящий ошибку.

Comment: Сделал, теперь можете посмотреть на результат при нажатии на - Кириллица

Comment: @НаильЯрулин у Вас заменяются теги тоже, а не только содержимое

Comment: а можно ли это как-то исправить? чтобы только изменялся текст, а теги не изменялись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что `innerHTML` содержит текст вместе с тегами и для `label` в такой разметке

```
<label class="btn-menu" for="hmt">
    <span class="first"></span>
    <span class="second"></span>
    <span class="third"></span>
</label>
```

он будет равен

```
<span class="first"></span>
<span class="second"></span>
<span class="third"></span>
```

При замене меняется также имя тега, что нарушает [спецификацию](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tag-name).

Для решения, нужно менять *только текст* и *только в текстовых элементах*.

Так как html является деревом, можно обойти его в глубину и если полученный узел дерева текстовый - произвести замену.

Например:

```js
var transformConfig = {
  latin: [
    ['А', 'A'],
    ['а', 'a'],
    ['Ә', 'Á'],
    ['ә', 'á'],
    ['Б', 'B'],
    ['б', 'b'],
    ['В', 'V'],
    ['в', 'v'],
    ['Г', 'G'],
    ['г', 'g'],
    ['Ғ', 'Ǵ'],
    ['ғ', 'ǵ'],
    ['Д', 'D'],
    ['д', 'd'],
    ['Е', 'E'],
    ['е', 'e'],
    ['Ж', 'J'],
    ['ж', 'j'],
    ['З', 'Z'],
    ['з', 'z'],
    ['И', 'I'],
    ['и', 'ı'],
    ['Й', 'I'],
    ['й', 'ı'],
    ['К', 'K'],
    ['к', 'k'],
    ['Қ', 'Q'],
    ['қ', 'q'],
    ['Л', 'L'],
    ['л', 'l'],
    ['М', 'M'],
    ['м', 'm'],
    ['Н', 'N'],
    ['н', 'n'],
    ['Ң', 'Ń'],
    ['ң', 'ń'],
    ['О', 'O'],
    ['о', 'o'],
    ['Ө', 'Ó'],
    ['ө', 'ó'],
    ['П', 'P'],
    ['п', 'p'],
    ['Р', 'R'],
    ['р', 'r'],
    ['С', 'S'],
    ['с', 's'],
    ['Т', 'T'],
    ['т', 't'],
    ['У', 'Ý'],
    ['у', 'ý'],
    ['Ұ', 'U'],
    ['ұ', 'u'],
    ['Ү', 'Ú'],
    ['ү', 'ú'],
    ['Ф', 'F'],
    ['ф', 'f'],
    ['Х', 'H'],
    ['х', 'h'],
    ['Һ', 'Һ'],
    ['һ', 'h'],
    ['Ц', 'Ts'],
    ['ц', 'ts'],
    ['Ч', 'Ch'],
    ['ч', 'ch'],
    ['Ш', 'Sh'],
    ['ш', 'sh'],
    ['Ы', 'Y'],
    ['ы', 'y'],
    ['І', 'I'],
    ['і', 'i'],
    ['Э', 'E'],
    ['э', 'e'],
    ['Ю', 'Iý'],
    ['ю', 'iý'],
    ['Я', 'Ia'],
    ['я', 'ia'],
    ['Щ', ''],
    ['Ь', ''],
    ['Ъ', ''],
    ['щ', ''],
    ['ь', ''],
    ['ъ', ''],
    ['ё', ''],
    ['Ё', ''],
  ],
  cyrillic: [
    ['А', 'A'],
    ['а', 'a'],
    ['Á', 'Ә'],
    ['á', 'ә'],
    ['B', 'Б'],
    ['b', 'б'],
    ['V', 'В'],
    ['v', 'в'],
    ['G', 'Г'],
    ['g', 'г'],
    ['Ǵ', 'Ғ'],
    ['ǵ', 'ғ'],
    ['D', 'Д'],
    ['d', 'д'],
    ['Е', 'E'],
    ['е', 'e'],
    ['J', 'Ж'],
    ['j', 'ж'],
    ['Z', 'З'],
    ['z', 'з'],
    ['I', 'И'],
    ['ı', 'и'],
    ['I', 'Й'],
    ['ı', 'й'],
    ['К', 'K'],
    ['k', 'к'],
    ['Q', 'Қ'],
    ['q', 'қ'],
    ['L', 'Л'],
    ['l', 'л'],
    ['М', 'M'],
    ['m', 'м'],
    ['N', 'Н'],
    ['n', 'н'],
    ['Ń', 'Ң'],
    ['ń', 'ң'],
    ['О', 'O'],
    ['о', 'o'],
    ['Ó', 'Ө'],
    ['ó', 'ө'],
    ['P', 'П'],
    ['p', 'п'],
    ['R', 'Р'],
    ['r', 'р'],
    ['S', 'С'],
    ['s', 'с'],
    ['Т', 'T'],
    ['t', 'т'],
    ['Ý', 'У'],
    ['ý', 'у'],
    ['U', 'Ұ'],
    ['u', 'ұ'],
    ['Ú', 'Ү'],
    ['ú', 'ү'],
    ['F', 'Ф'],
    ['f', 'ф'],
    ['H', 'Х'],
    ['h', 'х'],
    ['Һ', 'Һ'],
    ['h', 'һ'],
    ['Ts', 'Ц'],
    ['ts', 'ц'],
    ['Ch', 'Ч'],
    ['ch', 'ч'],
    ['Sh', 'Ш'],
    ['sh', 'ш'],
    ['Y', 'Ы'],
    ['y', 'ы'],
    ['І', 'I'],
    ['і', 'i'],
    ['E', 'Е'],
    ['e', 'е'],
    ['Iý', 'Ю'],
    ['iý', 'ю'],
    ['Ia', 'Я'],
    ['ia', 'я'],
    ['Э', ''],
    ['э', ''],
  ]
};

function transform(type) {
  // выполняем дальше если есть такое свойство
  if (typeof transformConfig[type] !== 'undefined') {
    // находим все элементы на странице
    var collection = Array.from(document.body.childNodes);
    // перебираем все элементы на странице
    while (collection.length) {
      var node = collection.shift();
      if (node.nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE && node.childNodes.length) {
        collection.unshift(...node.childNodes);
        continue;
      }
      transformConfig[type].forEach(function(chars) {

        var pattern = new RegExp(
          chars[0],
          'g'
        );
        // изменяем innerHTML
        node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(
          pattern,
          chars[1]
        )
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.hidden-menu {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 20vh;
  padding-left: 0vh;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #B0E0E6;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
  transition: left .2s;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker {
  display: none;
}

.btn-menu {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #7B68EE;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: left .23s;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.btn-menu span {
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  transition: all .1s linear .23s;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-menu span.first {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.btn-menu {
  left: 160px;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.hidden-menu {
  left: 0;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.btn-menu span.first {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 10px;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.btn-menu span.second {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.btn-menu span.third {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<h1 class="wrapper-logo">test</h1>
<button onclick="transform('latin')" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px">Латинский</button>
<button onclick="transform('cyrillic')" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 400px">Кириллица</button>
<h2 class="wrapper-welcome">test</h2>

<!--Боковое меню-->
<input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker">
<label class="btn-menu" for="hmt">
  <span class="first"></span>
  <span class="second"></span>
    <span class="third"></span>
 </label>
<ul class="hidden-menu">
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, вы мне очень помогли!!!

Comment: @НаильЯрулин, обрати внимание, что у тебя не совсем корректный алгоритм замены, буква `ц` при переводе в латиницу и обратно трансформируется в `ts` и  `тс` соответственно

Comment: А разве не правильно?

Comment: @НаильЯрулин, нет, у тебя слово "кириллица" превращается в "кириллитса"

Comment: А да, блин, но я же превращаю ts в ц

Comment: @НаильЯрулин, но проходишь-то ты по одному символу.

Comment: к idx нужно прибавлять 2?

Comment: или chars, я не помню уже, я на этой функцией работал неделю, т.к. недавно начал изучать javascript

Comment: @НаильЯрулин, а не, по одному все правильно, по одному элементу массива, проблема в том, что ты сначала доходишь до `t`, и заменяешь его на `т` а когда доходишь до `ts` у тебя `t` уже заменена и ты его просто не находишь

Comment: а как можно это исправить?(

Comment: если вообще можно

Comment: @НаильЯрулин, в общем случае транслитерация не тривиальная задача. как раз из за таких проблем когда надо сливать "тс" в "ц" а когда нет.

Comment: что тогда делать?

Comment: @НаильЯрулин, можно оставить как есть.

Comment: Просто эта функция пойдет на сайт, на который будут заходить люди, меня попросили сделать такую функцию, а тут у меня такие косяки(

Comment: @НаильЯрулин, функция работает, проблемы только в специфических случаях. На сколько часто они будут появляться - неизвестно

Comment: Ну хорошо, и можно ещё 1 вопрос? Где вы изучали JavaScript?